# RTL excel Arabic report - C#

Tags: c#, excel, localization, spreadsheetlight

In my application, I have the following requirement.

An excel report is to be generated in English and Arabic. In English (or any other non-Arabic language) report should open in left to right direction. And in Arabic it should open from right to left.

I have created the excel document using C#. Now the issue is:

The **Arabic report** I am generating in  my code is opening in **Left to Right direction** even in the Arabic Pack of excel.

I am using SpreadSheetLight

Answer (score 0):

SpreadsheetLight doesn't support Right to Left layout at the moment.